# Instanciar uma classe Java de diretório externo em JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Criei meu aplicativo `Java` com `Eclipse` no diretório `Meus Documentos/workspace/TesteJAVA/`

Agora quero chamar uma classe com `JSP`, quero saber como configurar para pegar o aplicativo deste diretório ou devo manter o aplicativo e as classes na pasta do `Tomcat` ?.

Estou usando `Apache Tomcat 8` e a página está em `C:Aplicativos/Apache/Tomcat8/webapps/TesteJSP/`

Comment: Bom, só pra nível de esclarecimento, qual o motivo de essa classe não está inserida no projeto que contém a página?

Comment: @Weslley Tavares Nunca fiz isso funcionar antes, tem um arquivo JSP na pasta do tomcat que funciona com código java, esta é minha página HTML, devo incluir este arquivo no projeto pelo Eclipse ?

Comment: Eu não vejo problema nessa inclusão.

Comment: @Weslley Tavares Ok, tento incluir arquivo JSP, mas o Eclipse fecha automaticamente, vou reinstalar os módulos e tentar novamente.

Comment: Qual perspectiva do eclipse tu estás usando?

Comment: @Weslley Tavares Última versão do Eclipse Mars + JBoss Tools, mas estava dando erro ao instalar, a tarde vou tentar novamente.

Comment: Então, quanto a perspectiva, você está na java ee?

Comment: @Weslley Tavares Sim

Comment: Estou sem computador pra tentar simular seu caso...

Comment: @Weslley Tavares Mas está correto isto né ? Java EE + o Jbos para permitir criar Projetos Web Dinâmicos..., se for isto eu vou tentar resolver, a questão mesmo é que não me liguei que deveria incluir o JSP no projeto, tão simples, mas como estou começando...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem duas opções:

1. Criar um projeto Web no Eclipse e deixar que ele monte o pacote para você.
2. Você precisa copiar os arquivos `.class` dentro do diretório `WEB-INF/classes` em seu projeto. Exemplo (colocar dentro de):

   C:/Aplicativos/Apache/Tomcat8/webapps/TesteJSP/WEB-INF/classes

Lembre-se que o os caracteres maiúsculos e minúsculos fazem diferença.

Answer (score 1):

Agora sim, tudo funcionando.

Primeiro instalei no Eclipse os softwares

- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
- Eclipse Web Developer Tools
- Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

Conforme descrito na resposta com mais votos desta pergunta:
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531402/newbie-in-eclipse-i-dont-have-dynamic-web-project-i-am-under-linux-ubuntu`

Segundo, criei o arquivo `JSP` no projeto, conforme descrito por @LeonardoCosta e @WeslleyTavares, porem o mesmo apresentou um erro, resolvido com a resposta da seguinte pergunta:

`http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94987/como-resolver-o-erro-the-superclass-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-was-not-f`

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado por dar sua resposta, ajuda aos novos que tem a mesma dúvida :-)