# Como resolver o erro - The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path

Tags: java, java-ee, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Estou usando **Eclipse Mars.1** para desenvolvimento Web, recebi este erro ao incluir um arquivo `JSP`, `The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path`.

Também tenho o Tomcat 8 rodando no PC.

Comment: Bem mais simples é só adicionar o Java EE5 libraries no build path

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assim como acontece com o banco de dados, o **Eclipse** não reconhece o serviço do **Apache Tomcat** apenas por ele estar presente no sistema, é necessário um plugin para o **Eclipse**.

- No Eclipse vá em Window **>** Preferences **>** Server **>** Runtime Environments **>** Add **>** Apache Tomcat 8 **>** e defina o diretório que o Tomcat foi instalado, no meu caso `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0` ex:

[image: Exemplo]

- Agora selecione o seu projeto e clique com botão direito **>** Properties **>** Project Facets **>** Runtimes **>** selecione o **Apache Tomcat 8**, aplicar e de um **OK** ex:

[image: Exemplo]

O erro deve ter desaparecido, tentando corrigir o problema, antes de tudo isto instalei no **Eclipse** um plugin do **Tomcat** e um software **Jboss Apache Tomcat Integration**, mas não sei até onde estes são necessários.

Answer (score 9):

A solução que encontrei foi um pouco diferente, e vou deixar aqui pois apenas adicionar o servidor e alterar o Project Facets não me ajudou:

1. No arquivo *pom.xml*, no campo destinado às dependências, adicione:

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
>   <version>3.1.0</version>
>   <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. A alteração deve ser reconhecida imediatamente; do contrário, clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre o seu projeto, opção **Maven** --> **Update Project** (ou apenas Alt+F5).

Comment: Esta é a solução se o projeto usa Maven e o Eclipse tem instalado o plugin M2E (Maven 2 Eclipse). A versão (`3.1.0`) está correta para o Tomcat 8 conforme a [documentação](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html). Quem usar versão diferente do servidor, precisa verificar a versão correta da API.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite pessoal

a solução ai de adicionar a dependência no Maven resolve também.
Apenas pra ajudar, pode ser resolvido da primeira forma que foi sugerido, adicionando a Target Runtime no Project Facets.
Acontece que depois de fazer isso, é preciso também configurar o projeto para utilizar as bibliotecas do server em questão.
Para isso, vá até as configurações de Build Path, na aba "Libraries" aperte o botão "Add Library", selecione "Server Runtime" e em seguida o Server que você utilizou, no meu caso "Tomcat 7.0"
Depois é só aplicar e pronto.